# Django checkbox want to check only a subset of the list of items

Tags: python, html, django, checkbox, subset

another checkbox question. I have items in a list. Each item has a checkbox. What I want to do is What I want to do is to tick all the items that are a subset of items. The subset of  `items = client.storageitem_set.all()` is `items = models.StorageItem.objects.filter(orderstoragelist__order__pk = order.pk)` This is defined in another view called edit_order.

So in views.edit_order, there is a subset list of teams. I go to views.client_items This is where I want all subset of items to be ticked in the checkbox. Right now  the code just checks for the *first* item. I don't want this anymore. I want to check The subset of items instead.

```
def client_items(request, client_id = 0):
    client = None
    items = None
    try:
        client = models.Client.objects.get(pk = client_id)
        items = client.storageitem_set.all()
    except:
        return HttpResponse(reverse(return_clients))
    return render_to_response('items.html', {'items':items, 'client':client}, context_instance = RequestContext(request)) # Redirect after POST


{% for item in items %}
            <tr class="items_table_row">
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{item.pk}}" value="{{item.pk}}" "{% ifequal forloop.counter 1 %} checked="checked"{% endifequal %}>
                    <td>{{item.tiptop_id}}</td><td>{{item.alternative_id}}</td><td>{{item.title}}</td><td>{{item.type}}</td><td>{{item.format}}</td>
                    <td><span id="{{item.pk}}" name="type">{{item.itemstatushistory_set.latest}}</span></td><td>{{item.itemstatushistory_set.latest.date.date|date:"d M Y"}}</td>
                    <td><a href="{% url tiptop.views.edit_item item.client.pk item.pk %}" onclick="return showAddAnotherPopup(this);">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: How are you expecting to get the list from a different view? How does it get to *this* view?

Comment: @Daniel, Basically in views.edit_order, it has a list of items but not all. Just the one which have been ordered. So for each view.edit order, there is a button that redirects them to the items list page. All the items are listed. I want all the items that was listed in views.edit_order to be checked in the full items list. The other items should be unticked.

Comment: If I was you I would have tried to do this with django forms and then create the proper initial dict for the form.

Comment: if I say "{% ifequal forloop.counter 1 %} This will give me the first entry. SO Instead of looking for one entry, why can't I say {% ifequal forloop.counter views.edit_order %}? This does not work

Comment: In addition I could also say {% ifequal item.tiptop_id 0123 %} I will get the item_id = "0123"

Comment: You seem very confused. How could a counter (0, 1, 2, 3 etc) be equal to a view?

Comment: @daniel. Ok, even I am getting confused so ignore all earlier comments and look at this. {% if item.tiptop_id == tiptop.views.edit_order.item.tiptop_id %} checked="checked"{% endif %} This is what I want to say. All the items listed in edit order views to be checked in the items list and the rest not checked. Unfortunately this does not work. But at least you can get the idea what I am after now.

Answer (score 0):

This may help though I've never done this before, assuming you have some model `M` you just need to render it's form with the data/options you need and apply onto subset.

```
# Model
class M(models.Model):
    status = models.BooleanField() # this will be our checkbox
    # your stuffs

# Model's form
class MForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = M

        widgets = {
            'status': CheckboxInput(attrs = {'checked': 'checked'}),
        }
```

Sultan

Comment: I have already have a checkbox for both views.edit_order (subset) and views.client_items (full list). I can tick all items and I can tick at least on item at a time (the above code). So I am not really sure why I need to render a class form.